# Address Locator "Geocoding service"

Tags: arcgis-server, geocoding, arcgis-rest-api, address

I've already created an Address Locator sucessfuly and published it as a Geocoding service, but I need to verify  that its working from the rest since its not working from my web mapping application is there a method to do this ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is provided in the following screenshot

In Step number 3 " choose a locator" browse and select the published geocoding service from your server.

[image]